# How to identify different memory regions of an elf binary in radare2?

Tags: debugging, radare2, elf

I'm just starting out with reverse engineering, one thing I'm finding difficult is identifying different areas of memory. I'm using radare2, and I would like to be able to easily seek and identify different sections of memory (e.g. data/text/stack/heap etc):

Is there an easy way to do this within radare2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to list the sections and segments of a program using radare2.

**Sections**
Use `iS` to list the program's Sections:

```
[0x00001c50]> iS
[Sections]
Nm Paddr       Size Vaddr      Memsz Perms Name
00 0x00000000     0 0x00000000     0 ----
01 0x00000238    28 0x00000238    28 -r-- .interp
02 0x00000254    32 0x00000254    32 -r-- .note.ABI_tag
03 0x00000274    36 0x00000274    36 -r-- .note.gnu.build_id
04 0x00000298   100 0x00000298   100 -r-- .gnu.hash
<truncated for readability>
19 0x00007bf0     8 0x00207bf0     8 -rw- .init_array
20 0x00007bf8     8 0x00207bf8     8 -rw- .fini_array
21 0x00007c00    88 0x00207c00    88 -rw- .data.rel.ro
22 0x00007c58   496 0x00207c58   496 -rw- .dynamic
23 0x00007e48   440 0x00207e48   440 -rw- .got
24 0x00008000   128 0x00208000   128 -rw- .data
25 0x00008080     0 0x00208080   416 -rw- .bss
26 0x00008080    52 0x00000000    52 ---- .gnu_debuglink
27 0x000080b4   257 0x00000000   257 ---- .shstrtab
```

**Segements**
 Use `iSS` to list its Segments:

```
[0x00001c50]> iSS
[Segments]
Nm Paddr       Size Vaddr      Memsz Perms Name
00 0x00000040   504 0x00000040   504 -r-x PHDR
01 0x00000238    28 0x00000238    28 -r-- INTERP
02 0x00000000 28120 0x00000000 28120 -r-x LOAD0
03 0x00007bf0  1168 0x00207bf0  1584 -rw- LOAD1
04 0x00007c58   496 0x00207c58   496 -rw- DYNAMIC
05 0x00000254    68 0x00000254    68 -r-- NOTE
06 0x000060a4   580 0x000060a4   580 -r-- GNU_EH_FRAME
07 0x00000000     0 0x00000000     0 -rw- GNU_STACK
08 0x00007bf0  1040 0x00207bf0  1040 -r-- GNU_RELRO
09 0x00000000    64 0x00000000    64 -rw- ehdr
```

**Memory maps**
If you want to list different memory maps of a running executable, including the Heap and Stack, this can also be done with radare2. This is relevant only when you are debugging a program (using `r2 -d <program>`):

```
[0x7f5e8d50bca6]> dm
0x000055e186c63000 - 0x000055e186c6b000 - usr    32K s r-x /usr/bin/cat /usr/bin/cat ; map.usr_bin_cat.r_x
0x000055e186e6a000 - 0x000055e186e6b000 - usr     4K s r-- /usr/bin/cat /usr/bin/cat ; map.usr_bin_cat.rw
0x000055e186e6b000 - 0x000055e186e6c000 - usr     4K s rw- /usr/bin/cat /usr/bin/cat ; section..data
0x000055e188c8b000 - 0x000055e188cac000 - usr   132K s rw- [heap] [heap]
0x00007f5e8d446000 - 0x00007f5e8d5f9000 * usr   1.7M s r-x /usr/lib/libc-2.27.so /usr/lib/libc-2.27.so
<truncated for readability>
0x00007f5e8da28000 - 0x00007f5e8da29000 - usr     4K s rw- unk2 unk2 ; map.unk0.rw
0x00007ffffa7d7000 - 0x00007ffffa7f8000 - usr   132K s rw- [stack] [stack] ; map.stack_.rw
0x00007ffffa7f9000 - 0x00007ffffa7fc000 - usr    12K s r-- [vvar] [vvar] ; map.vvar_.r
0x00007ffffa7fc000 - 0x00007ffffa7fe000 - usr     8K s r-x [vdso] [vdso] ; map.vdso_.r_x
```